# How do I count characters in full String like “Good Morning ”?

Tags: javascript, string, hashmap

I want to get number of each character’s occurrence including spaces and marks like (?-!-&..etc) but I don’t know how all I found was about one string only like “abcd” .. and I want something like “Good Morning!” And to count spaces too *USING JAVASCRIPT * , Thank you

Comment: Your question body says Java but you used the JavaScript tag. Which is it?

Comment: I meant JavaScript sorry !

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following example

```js
const string = "Good Morning!";

const output = string.split("").reduce((tally, value) => {
  tally[value] = tally[value] ? tally[value] + 1 : 1;

  return tally;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

See

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: I tried to run this code on netbeans but it gave me many errors !! and I would like to ask if there is a way to do it with hashmap ?

Comment: This code works on nodejs and in the browser. Apparently what you require is a solution in Java